# Unit tests run as scalatest in intellij but the same fails in build

Tags: scala, unit-testing, gradle, mockito, scalatest

I am using scalatest for unit testing my scala code with intellij, gradle, mockito.

There are few testcases which run absolutely fine when run as scalatests ,however fail when running as part of gradle build.

I have added scalatest dependencies,maiflai scalatest ,mockito and other dependencies into my build.gradle.

Can anyone let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Please provide more information (like stacktrace), anyone who wants to answer this must know what is happening.

Comment: As well as pls add Java, Scala, Gradle, and other dependencies versions.

Comment: There are no errors,  it's just that the assertions fail. For example, If scalatest evaluates a condition to be true, when running the same with gradle builds the test fails saying the result was false

Comment: classpath 'org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.8'
classpath "gradle.plugin.com.github.maiflai:gradle-scalatest:0.32"
classpath "org.scoverage:ğradle-scoverage:7.0.0"

test Implementation 'junit: junit:4.12'
test Implementation 'org.scalatest:scalatest 2.11:3.2.11
test Implementation 'org.mockito:mockito-scala_2.11:1.17.0'
testRuntime Only 'org.scala-lang.modules:scala-xml 2.11:1.3.0
test Implementation 'com.vladsch.flexmark: flexmark-util:0.62.2'
testRuntime Only "com.vladsch.flexmark: flexmark-all:0.62.2"
testRuntimeOnly("com.vladsch.flexmark: flexmark-profile-pegdown:0.62.2")

Comment: @Amy won't be able to answer the question with partial information.

Comment: test( testName = "getDFForFileExtract - csv file") {
val hiveExtractQuery = "select * from db1.table1"
when(sparkMock.sqlchiveExtractQuery)). thenAnswer(localdf)
val (resof, resValue) = FileExtract.getDFForFileExtract(sparkMock, fileExtract)
assert(resValue =: 1)
assert (resdf.count() == 3)
)
}

Comment: This is the code I executed with scalatest and assertions pass, but fails when running the build. SparkMock is mock for sparksession while localDf is dataframe from a file.

Comment: Can you please add stack trace if possible